# Calculating dynamic difference between two columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, difference

I have a situation in which I need to calculate the difference between multiple columns and store them in a separate column under separate headers. My dataset looks like below:

```
cat_1   cat_2   cat_3      cat_4     date_1       date_2          date_3       date_4
 a       b        b         c        2020-01-01   2020-01-01      2020-01-25   2020-01-10
 b                c         d        2019-01-11   2020-01-01      2020-01-15   2020-01-10
 a       b                  d        2018-11-01   2019-01-01      2020-01-15   2020-01-10
 a       b        c         d        2015-01-01   2016-01-29      2018-01-25   2019-01-10
```

.. and so on
The order will follow : a->b->c->d and the reverse is not true
I want to store the following combinations in new columns in number of days. There will be 4 combinations in total. Essentially I want to calculate the difference in two dates and store in days for the combination.

**An example output for the first row of my dataset:**

```
days_a-b    days_a-c   days_a-d     days_b-c       days_b-d      days_c-d  
0           9                                                     
                                    355            364           -5
```

How to solve this one?

Comment: can be done using[`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) or [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

Comment: what does a,b,c and d represent?  Are those columns

Comment: I don't see the pattern